# D3.js - ошибка Cannot read property 'force' of undefined

Tags: d3.js

Скопировал пример использования `D3.js`
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642#graph.json

Но при открытии файла в браузере - ничего не прорисовывается.

В деталях высвечивается ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'force' of undefined
>       at index.html:31

Скачал последнюю версию библиотеки, так же пробовал подключать и эту http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что js пытается считать поле force у объекта, хотя вместо объекта переменная оказалась пустой. Трудно понять почему именно ошибка, т.к. вы вообще не предоставили никаких данных. Возможно код неверно скопировали.

В примере из вашей ссылки есть ссылка [open](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/950642), она откроет нужный пример в отдельной вкладке.